# Invert X and Y coordinates on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, canvas

I am working on an interface that has a HTML5 canvas on it, and I need to invert the X and Y coordinates when you select a position.  I thought that subtracting the width of the canvas from the selected X position, and subtracting the height of the canvas from the selected Y position would invert the coordinates, but it is doing some very weird things.

The X and Y coords that log when you click in the top left corner of the canvas are `X:324,Y:483` but theoretically, they should be `X:650,Y:587`, and when you click in the bottom right corner, the logged coordinates are `X:-325,Y:-103` when they theoretically should be `X:0,Y:0`.  As a side note, I do know that the dot that appears when you click is using the inverted coordinates, and that is fine.

Any help is appreciated especially if I am doing something horribly wrong.  Thanks!

JS:

```
window.fires.directive('fieldDirective', ['ScoutService', '$interval', function(ScoutService, $interval) {
    var $scope = this;
    $scope.sServ = ScoutService;
    $interval(function(){
        $scope.col = ScoutService.getAllianceColor();
    },1);
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element) {
            element.bind('mousedown', function(event) {
                var canvas = document.getElementById('field');
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                if(event.offsetX !== undefined) {
                    $scope.xPos = 650 - event.offsetX;
                    $scope.yPos = 587 - event.offsetY;
                    $scope.sServ.sendLobCoords(xPos, yPos);
                } else {
                    $scope.xPos = 650 - event.layerX - event.currentTarget.offsetLeft;
                    $scope.yPos = 587 - event.layerY - event.currentTarget.offsetTop;
                    $scope.sServ.sendLobCoords(xPos, yPos);
                }
                console.log('red'+$scope.xPos + ' ' + $scope.yPos);
                canvas.width = canvas.width;
                context.arc($scope.xPos, $scope.yPos, 12, 0, Math.PI*2);
                context.fillStyle = '#FFFF00';
                context.fill();
                context.lineWidth = 3;
                context.strokeStyle = '#B2B200';
                context.stroke();
                context.closePath();
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<canvas field-directive id="field" ng-class="{'field-red': sCtrl.fieldColor === 'red', 'field-blue': sCtrl.fieldColor === 'blue'}" width="650" height="587">Your browser does not support the HTML5 Canvas Element.  Please use a supported browser such as Google Chrome 4.0+ or FireFox 2.0+.</canvas>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First make the x and y relative to the canvas element itself by subtracting the position of the element from the client coordinates
- Then subtract the adjusted x *from* width, y *from* height
- If you need an absolute position, add back the offsets

Example modification:

```
element.bind('mousedown', function(event) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('field');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    // get element position
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

    // get inversed coordinates: enable code after comment if abs. pos.
    var ix = canvas.width - (event.clientX - rect.left); // + rect.left
    var iy = canvas.height - (event.clientY - rect.top); // + rect.top

    ...update $scope here etc...
});
```

#### Live demo:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('field');

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
  var canvas = document.getElementById('field');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  // get element position
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

  // get inversed coordinates: enable code after comment if abs. pos.
  var ix = canvas.width - (event.clientX - rect.left); // + rect.left
  var iy = canvas.height - (event.clientY - rect.top); // + rect.top

  // draw something
  context.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 180);
  context.fillRect(ix - 2, iy - 2, 4, 4);
});
```

```css
canvas {border: 1px solid #007}
```

```html
<canvas id="field" width=500 height=180></canvas>
```

Comment: Your code snippet was very nice, and it working perfectly in my application (after I fixed all of my stupid spelling mistakes :P), Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, The comment you left `enable code after comment if abs. pos.` does not actually give the abs. position of where you clicked on the canvas. To fix this, I did not add in what you suggested, but instead removed the `canvas.width - ` and the `canvas.height - `, and it worked perfectly as the absolute positions.

Comment: @Burn_E99 ah, my mistake. I assumed absolute position to the *inverted* coordinates relative to canvas.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is arising because offsetX and offsetY are tied to the item that was clicked. In this case whatever "element" is. If the click event were tied directly to the canvas I think your code would work.

Try binding the event to the canvas itself or use the position of the element with the click behavior and the position of the canvas to do corrective math.

Comment: Would you be able to show me an example of binding it to the canvas itself? I am not sure of how to do this.

Comment: Hopefully someone who knows angular better can guide you. The math for the points is correct and I made almost the same code work perfectly when the element was defined as being the canvas. Maybe you can console.log the element and see what it is. I can't make this code run standalone to help debug.

Comment: Ok, when I logged the variable `element`, it returned this object: `Object { 0: <canvas#field.field-red>, length: 1 }`, which is the exact canvas that I need to be referenced.  Just so that I understand when you said 'The math for the points is correct...', were you referring to my math to invert the coordinates?

Comment: Yes. I copy pasted your code and wrote some jQuery to run it and it worked.