# How to draw six lines symmetrically spaced in a radius in Canvas?

Tags: javascript, math, html5-canvas

I am trying to build a snowflake drawing app in Canvas, very similar to this: http://www.pumpkinpirate.info/ks/.

Basically, if you draw a dot, it should be repeated 5 more times in a symmetrical circle pattern within the canvas. Here's an illustration:

[image: snowflake concept]

I know how to tell the canvas to draw something multiple times, but my math skills are limited and I am wondering how to calculate the position of the 5 copied dots in relation to the original one.

I am thinking that I have to find the middle of the canvas and calculate the distance from that to the x and y positions of the original dot. After that I assume maybe I have to find the radius of if I was to draw a circle from that point and then... this is when my head starts smoking.

I am wondering if I can do something similar to what they are doing here:
[Invert X and Y coordinates on HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28574628/invert-x-and-y-coordinates-on-html5-canvas)

Just for background, I originally started out with 6 clipped canvases where 5 were rotated and would copy the first one, but I realized that this approach didn't really work, partly because the canvases would overlap each other slightly (but there were other issues too).

Here is the code I have so far:

```
drawing = false;
startX = 0;
startY = 0;
imageData = null;

const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startPosition());
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", endPosition());
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw());

function startPosition(e) {
  const canvas = this;
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  startX = e.clientX;
  startY = e.clientY;
  imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
  drawing = true;
}

function endPosition(e) {
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  ctx.lineWidth = 4;
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
  ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
  ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();

  drawing = false;
}
function draw(e) {
  const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  if(!drawing) {
    return;
  }

  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
  ctx.lineWidth = 4;
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
  ctx.moveTo(startX, startY);
  ctx.lineTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);    
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(e.clientX, e.clientY);

  //draw line 2
  ctx.moveTo(startX - 50, startY - 50);
  ctx.lineTo(e.clientX - 50, e.clientY - 50);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(e.clientX - 50, e.clientY - 50);

  //draw line 3
  ctx.moveTo(startX - 100, startY - 100);
  ctx.lineTo(e.clientX - 100, e.clientY - 100);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(e.clientX - 100, e.clientY - 100);
}
```

Comment: Regarding the math: I think you want 12 equivalent points, not 6. Look at the "prongs" on [this snowflake](https://www.thephoblographer.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/15163801364_308edf961e_k.jpg): each endpoint has 12 "copies": 6 on the right and 6 on the left of each branch. Mathematically speaking, you need 5 points generated with rotation by 60 degrees around the center, and the other 6 points generated from these using a reflection (in the linked snowflake imagine a reflection with respect to the vertical axis that corresponds to a `(x,y) <-> (-x,y)` transformation.

Comment: If you only use the 6 rotated versions you get things like [this but with 6 legs rather than the 3 in the image](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/36/The_armoured_triskelion_on_the_flag_of_the_Isle_of_Man.svg/1200px-The_armoured_triskelion_on_the_flag_of_the_Isle_of_Man.svg.png). You don't want feet on only one side of each leg.

Comment: Thanks Andreas! Yes I do see what you are saying. My inspiration for this was a snowflake generator in a Jaquie Lawson advent calendar and that one has 6 sections, but each section mirrors itself as you draw, so you end up with 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rotate a point around another point

```
const center = {x: 100, y: 100};   // Point to rotate around
const point = {x: ?, y: ?};        // Point to rotate
const rotate = (Math.PI * 2) / 5;  // Rotate 1/5th of 360


// Get the vector from center to point
const vx = point.x - center.x;
const vy = point.y - center.y;

// Get the transformation (2D uniform rotate)
const xAx = Math.cos(rotate);
const xAy = Math.sin(rotate); 

// Transform the vector (rotates) and translate back to center
const tx = vx * xAx - vy * xAy + center.x;
const ty = vx * xAy + vy * xAx + center.y;
```

As a function

```
function rotate(point, center, rotate, result = {}) {
    const vx = point.x - center.x;
    const vy = point.y - center.y;
    const xAx = Math.cos(rotate);
    const xAy = Math.sin(rotate); 
    result.x = vx * xAx - vy * xAy + center.x;
    result.y = vx * xAy + vy * xAx + center.y;
    return result;
}
```

To create the 5 points from 1 using the above function

```
const slices = 5; // number of rotations
const center = {x: 100, y: 100}; // center point

// Rotates point steps times around center
// Returns array of points
function rotateAll(point, steps, result = []) {
    const ang = Math.PI * 2 / steps;
    result.push(point);                      // Add first point
    for (let rot = 1; rot < steps; rot++) {  // Add remaining points
        result.push(rotate(point, center, rot * ang));
    }
    return result;
}

// Usage
const points = rotateAll({x: 10, y: 20}, slices);
```

Comment: You want 5 rotations with _one sixth_ of a circle (`PI/3`), because there are six copies (but you already have the original point).

Comment: @AndrasDeak The constant `slices` defines the number of points. Bottom snippet.

Comment: In the top one you have `(Math.PI * 2) / 5;  // Rotate 1/5th of 360` which can't be right. And I don't know JS (?) but it seems to me that `slices` is being passed as `steps` into `rotateAll`, so you're passing `5` again which goes into `const ang = Math.PI * 2 / steps;`. That would still mean 72-degree rotations, not 60-degree ones. You need `steps` iterations of the loop but `Math.PI * 2 / (steps + 1)` as rotation angle.

Comment: @AndrasDeak The first value is arbitrary, can be any value. The function `rotateAll`  returns an array with argument `steps`  points. If the value `steps` is 5 then there are 5 points equally spaced around the circle, only the last 4 are rotated.

Comment: Ah, OK, your loop starts from 1, not 0. Then I understand, thanks. In that case I'd just change all the fives to sixes, because that's what OP seems to be asking (see [their image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nq9lk.jpg) and snowflake lore in general).

Comment: Thank you Blindman67! This works perfectly. Now I just need to figure out how to mirror the six points as Andreas Deak suggested. Here's a codepen of the snowflake drawing app so far:
https://codepen.io/moorehannah/pen/VwYyERG
(disclaimer: for some reason the point that is being drawn doesn't match the cursor position 100% in codepen, but it does in my local environment, so I am not going to worry about it for right now)

Comment: @hmoore  Mirror function (shorthand arg names: `p` is point to mirror, `mX` mirror X axis, `mY` mirror Y axis as bools, true to mirror axis, `c` is center (point to mirror on), and `r` is returned result.) The function `function mirrorPoint(p, mX, mY, c, r = {}) {r.x = (p.x - c.x) * (mX ? -1 : 1) + c.x; r.y = (p.y - c.y) * (mY ? -1 : 1) + c.y; return r;}` Usage: To mirror in in both X and Y axis use `const mirroredPoint mirrorPoint({x: 10, y: 20}, true, true, center);` (`center` as used in the answer)

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much @Blindman67! This is beautiful!
https://codepen.io/moorehannah/pen/VwYyERG